# I need left anti join in mongodb with lookup and match aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I want to convert this query in MongoDB

Select * from Question where not exists (select * from Solved_question where questionid = id and username=username)

Collections Schema

```
question:{ 
    _id:ObjectId,
    title:String,
    desc:string, 
    Author:string
 },
       
 User:{
    _id:ObjectId, 
    Email:string,
    Password:string
 },
Solvedquestioncollection:{
 Id:_id,
 QuestionId:{ type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:"Question" },
 UserId:{ type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:"User" } 
}
```

Sample Document

```
Question:[
{
 _id:ObjectId('1'),
title:"main component of computer",
desc:"some desc for this"
author:"ashick"
},
{
 _id:ObjectId('2'),
title:"Advantage of CPU",
desc:"some desc for this"
author:"ashick"
},
]

User:[
{
_id:ObjectId('1'),
email:"as@g.com",
password:"12345"
},
{
_id:ObjectId('2'),
email:"df@g.com",
password:"345"
}
]
solvedquestion:[
{
_id:ObjectId('1'),
question:ObjectId('2'),
userId:ObjectId('1')
},
{
_id:ObjectId('2'),
question:ObjectId('2'),
userId:ObjectId('2')
}
]
```

I want to Fetch the Question in Question Collection Which does not solved by a particular user

I try this

```
question = await Question.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "solvedquestions",
            let: { userId: "$userId" },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: ["ObjectId('60ebc6b9980b8e1f8cffe34b'"), "$$userId"],
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            as: "resultingArray",
          },
        },
        
      ]);
```

but its Return the Empty Array

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Please add some sample documents

Comment: Schema for this problem 

Question
{
_id:ObjectId,
title:String,
desc:string,
Author:string
}
User
{
_id:ObjectId,
Email:string, 
Password:string
}
Solvedquestioncollection 
{
Id:_id,
QuestionId:{
    type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:"Question"
}
UserId:{
    type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:"User"
}
}

Comment: @MdAashiq - please *edit your question* to provide clarifying detail such as schema, sample data, etc. These updates don't belong in comments, as they are very difficult to read as unformatted text.

Comment: Also, it's important to show what you mean by "it doesn't work properly" - what are the issues you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
let aggregate = Question.aggregate([
     {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'solvedquestions',
            let: {
              question_id: '$_id',
              question_userId: '$user'
            },
            pipeline: [ {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $eq: ['$QuestionId', '$$question_id']
                    },
                    {
                      $eq: ['$userId', '$$question_userId']
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }],
            as: 'results'
          }
        }
]);
 return await aggregate.exec();
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error ->',error);
}
```

I hope this helps, Let me know if you have any doubt. Happy to help :)

Comment: Note that the OP hasn't yet shown what specific issue(s) they encountered. Also, when answering such a question, be sure to explain why your solution fixes their problem. currently you only included an aggregation, with no explanation, and no input or output.

Comment: I added sample schema and sample document, I try to achieve join the question and solvedquestion collection then filter by userId then project question that not in that filter